# Python script using Glade code produces glib error about old version of GTK

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, glade

I am trying to create my first Glade GUI using Python as the back-end. I created the GUI in Glade and saved the file as a .glade. I then created my Python code and saved it in the same directory as the glade file. Upon running the Python file in the terminal, I receive the following message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "glade6.py", line 56, in <module>
        main = Buglump()
      File "glade6.py", line 20, in __init__
        self.builder.add_from_file("glade6.glade")
    glib.GError: glade6.glade: required gtk+ version 3.10, current version is 2.24
```

OS:
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit

And the Python file that was run:
Code acquired from 'http://gnipsel.com/glade/index.html'

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys

    try: 
      import gtk
      import gtk.glade
    except:
      print('GTK not available')
      sys.exit(1)
    try:
      import pygtk
      pygtk.require('2.0')
    except:
      pass

    class Buglump:

      def __init__(self):
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("glade6.glade")
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        # the liststore
        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(int,str)
        self.liststore.append([0,"Select an Item:"])
        self.liststore.append([1,"Row 1"])
        self.liststore.append([2,"Row 2"])
        self.liststore.append([3,"Row 3"])
        self.liststore.append([4,"Row 4"])
        self.liststore.append([5,"Row 5"])

        # the combobox
        self.combobox = self.builder.get_object("combobox1")
        self.combobox.set_model(self.liststore)
        self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.combobox.pack_start(self.cell, True)
        self.combobox.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 1)
        self.combobox.set_active(0)

        self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
        self.window1.show()

      def on_combobox1_changed(self, widget, data=None):
        self.index = widget.get_active()
        self.model = widget.get_model()
        self.item = self.model[self.index][1]
        print "ComboBox Active Text is", self.item
        print "ComboBox Active Index is", self.index
        self.builder.get_object("label1").set_text(self.item)

      def on_window1_destroy(self, object, data=None):
        print "quit with cancel"
        gtk.main_quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main = Buglump()
      gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 5):

`import gtk` actually imports `gtk+2.x`.
If you need to use `gtk+3`, assuming you already have it installed, you need to write:

```
From gi.repository import Gtk (with capital letter G)
```

Remove these lines:

```
import gtk

import gtk.glade
```

and remember to change all instances of `gtk` inside your code to `Gtk`. Example: change `gtk.main_quit()` to `Gtk.main_quit()`

Answer (score 0):

Was also getting the required gtk+ version 3x, current version is 2x error

The problem is that the newest version of Glade doesn't run with the default GTK version in Ubuntu.

I finally got it working by installing the older Glade V3.8.5 Note: I'm working on Xenial/16.04.

By installing the older version you can create Glade GUIs that run under GTK2.

Steps:

- remove the newer Glade (i.e. apt-get remove Glade) version
- download the V3.8.5 version of Glade (which is the last version to support GTK2) from: 
  http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glade/3.8/
- follow the install instructions (./configure, make, makeinstall)

I also needed to install these missing components (YMMV):

libgtk2.0-dev, intltool, libxml2-devel

It installed. But... when I ran it.. it died:

glade-3: error while loading shared libraries: libgladeui-1.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So finally I installed: libgladeui*

Rebooted... voila. Glade runs... the GUI I created works in Python2 (import gtk).